# .NET MAUI Deserialising to list viewmodel from test API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, maui

I have been using Xamarin Forms for a while but looking to start using .NET MAUI and I am having an issue when deserializing a response from my test API to a ViewModel List it is returning the list count but not binding the variables in the ViewModel if that makes sense.

I was using Newtonsoft which worked perfected but now I am on 6.0 I don't believe they support it so I am using the System.Text.Json library instead.

The code that worked was:

```
var response = client.GetAsync("WeatherForecast?format=json").Result
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherViewModel>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

But now when I use:

```
var response = client.GetAsync("WeatherForecast?format=json").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
   var responseData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<WeatherViewModel>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, options);
}
```

It gives me this in the debugger

[image: my viewmodel result]

But in the actual response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync the result is the following:

[image: api response]

The ViewModel is structured like this:

```
public class WeatherViewModel
{
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  public Int32 TemperatureC { get; set; }

  public Int32 TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

  public String Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the JSON it brings back from the call:

```
[
{
"date": "2023-02-15T18:42:26.4694349+00:00",
"temperatureC": 39,
"temperatureF": 102,
"summary": "Hot"
},
{
"date": "2023-02-16T18:42:26.4694515+00:00",
"temperatureC": -3,
"temperatureF": 27,
"summary": "Cool"
},
{
"date": "2023-02-17T18:42:26.4694523+00:00",
"temperatureC": -9,
"temperatureF": 16,
"summary": "Bracing"
},
{
"date": "2023-02-18T18:42:26.469453+00:00",
"temperatureC": 9,
"temperatureF": 48,
"summary": "Cool"
},
{
"date": "2023-02-19T18:42:26.4694537+00:00",
"temperatureC": 5,
"temperatureF": 40,
"summary": "Chilly"
}
]
```

So the problem I am having is that I am getting the JSON ok from the API Get but when I deserialize it it is not populating into the ViewModel but it is creating 5 counts in the list. Could anybody shed some light on this for me. It would be a massive help.

Comment: You have to replace the images by text. Nobody will type it manually. And pls show Weather ViewModel class. And I don't think it is a good idea to move to Text.Json. As you can see it can not deserialize even a simple json without a custom converter

Comment: And what is the problem ? Can you post json too pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is always bad idea to post images instead of text, so I can't even see what is the problem, but I can see that you must be need to add PropertyNameCaseInsensitive, since your class property names and json property names  differ. In Newtonsoft insensetivity is true by default.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true};

JsonSerializer.Deserialize<...>(json, options)
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response this must be something Newtonsoft does by default but adding that solved the problem. Many Thanks for the help and also the pointers on using SO in the future. (Y)